# How to retrieve youtube comments using Selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, selenium-webdriver

This is the code which I have written

```
for ele in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h3.yt-lockup-title"):

    anchor = ele.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    links.append("%s" % anchor.get_attribute('href'))

print "Links:\n", "\n".join(links), "\n"

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.Ct"):
        print element.text
```

The problem is this code returns empty string.

Comment: Which URL are you running it against?

Comment: 'http://www.youtube.com' this is the URL which I'm using

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve the comments?

Comment: Nope, never heard of this web-site.